# Inserir dados no banco com codeigniter

Tags: banco-de-dados, codeigniter, mysqli, crud, inserir

Fala galera tudo certo, estou com a seguinte duvida:

Preciso exibir e salvar dados no meu banco de dados mas conforme vou mostrar abaixo eu estou usando Joins para exibir, por exemplo o nome de um autor utilizando sua chave primaria.
Para exibição esta funcionando, mas quando vou utilizar meu método para inserir dados na tabela ele retorna um erro com a chave estrangeira, pelo que pude entender meu código esta tentando inserir o nome retornado como se ele fosse a chave a estrangeira como essa chave não ira existir ele da erro, abaixo código e imagens do que estou fazendo:

Minha tela de onde o nome do autor é exibido:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código utilizado para retornar os dados da tela acima:

```
function history($ccod) {
$this->db->select('dat, cliente, texto, comcod, cnome, username');
$this->db->where('cliente', $ccod);
$this->db->from('comentarios');
$this->db->join('clientes', 'clientes.ccod = comentarios.cliente');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.id = comentarios.autor');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

Meu código para inserir os dado no banco de dados:

```
function inserir_coment($data) {
    return $this->db->insert('comentarios', $data, "autor.comentarios = user.id");
    }
```

Erro retornado ao executar este código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que arrumando a sintaxe para inserir os dados meu problema seja solucionado, mas como sou iniciante não consegui resolver sozinho, para esta aplicação estou utilizando Codeigniter 3.1.3.

Comment: O que significa `autor.comentarios = user.id` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está dizendo que na tabela `comentarios` a coluna `autor` é uma chave estrangeira que referencia a tabela `users`. Ou seja, o que você disse mesmo.

Precisa haver um `user` com o `código` `fmlima4` conforme está no insert, ou precisa passar o código do usuário.

O terceiro argumento aqui não faz sentido, nunca vi três argumentos para `insert` sendo que o terceiro é `where`.

```
return $this->db->insert('comentarios', $data, "autor.comentarios = user.id");
```

Acho que você quis fazer isso

```
 $data["autor"] = $algumValorDaSessaoPorExemplo;
 return $this->db->insert('comentarios', $data);
```

Você pode acertar isso na sua View, por exemplo adicionado um `input` do tipo `hidden` para guardar o código do autor, e no seu controller onde você monta o array `$data` atribuir o valor desse `hidden` para a chave `autor`

Comment: consegui fazer da seguinte forma em minha viu criei a seguinte linha:

    <input type="hidden" name="autor" value="1"/>

assim ele salva os dados no banco mas ao mudar o código para 
    <input type="hidden" name="autor" value="<?php $_SESSION['usuario_logado']['id']; ?>"/>
ele não salva e também não acusa erro